# HTML button that uses Javascript to take whole webpage screenshot and saves it

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, content-script, chrome-extension-manifest-v2

I am new to chrome extensions and I am trying to build a google chrome extension that takes a screenshot and saves it on the PC. I've managed to create a HTML button in my popup page and link it to a content-script.js but I can't seem to get how to take a whole webpage screenshot and save it afterwards. If anyone has some experience with this please help :)

Comment: Please elaborate on "save it afterwards". This could be interpreted in many different ways, one approach could be to create a base64 string and send it to a service which stores it at a blob directory. Not sure that it is what you had in mind?

Comment: @Axtru 
basically that is what I am doing, but the problem is I have created a js file that connects to html button which is made to run content_script onclick and it allows me to run only one function but my screenshot method has many functions, that is where I am stuck. The screenshot method is working when used separated on a extension but not when used in another extension...

Comment: Not sure what you mean by: "The screenshot method is working when used separated on a extension but not when used in another extension...".

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can achieve it by using html2canvas.

https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the following method `captureVisibleTab` this uses the chrome browser api to fetch a image of the whole webpage.

https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/tabs/#method-captureVisibleTab